# data is appending multiple times when I submit form form 2nd time without form refresh

Tags: ajax, laravel, plugins, datatable

I am appending a data in table using ajax in laravel datatable plugin when through a modal. 
1). When I enter the data it append on table but at the same time it shows no data in datable until i refresh it

2). 2nd when I input data second time it appends on table multiple time

I tried this to reset the modal to check if it is due to the data inside the modal but still by applying this the modal hides  and form reset but still data input multiple times on 2nd time input

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {    
    $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
    $('#myModal').data('modal', null);
    $(this).removeData();
}

$('#submitDoc').click(function(){   
    $('.doc-form').on('submit', function(e){
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var no= {{ $no }};
    token =$('input[name=_token]').val();
    name = $('input[name=name]').val();
    start_date =  $('input[name=start_date]').val();
    end_date = $('input[name=end_date]').val();
    amount = $('input[name=amount]').val();
    image =$('input[name=select_file]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : '{{ URL("addDoc") }}',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: new FormData(this)
    }).done(function(data){ 
$('.docTable').append(
            "<tr>"+"<td class='text-center'>" + no++  + "</td>" +
            "<td class='text-center'>" + data.id+ "</td>"+ 
            "<td class='text-left'>" +data.name+ "</td>"+
            "<td class='text-center'>" +start_date +
            "</td>"+"<td class='text-center'>" +end_date+ "</td>"+
            "<td class='text-right'>" +'$'+ data.amount + 
            "</td>"+"<td class='text-center'>" + 
            "<i class='fa fa-camera'></i> "+ "</td>"+"</tr>");
    });
```

I want to append data in table on form submit without refreshing it perfectly that means not multiple time on single input and also when i submit the record in datatable it increments the record entry in page filter

[this is the screenshot of the table for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdkaX.png)

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this? Also what is the data source of datatable?

Comment: the data is coming from the database using ajax

Comment: no I didn't tried fiddle as I'm a beginner I don't know about these things too much

Comment: I have solved my first problem but the data is still adding number of times I opened the modal

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ just paste your html and js here and run/save, give the link here so it's easily debugged

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my first problem that is when I was appending the data in table the record counter does not increment. The correct way to add rows in table is

```
t.row.add( [  count++ ,
                 id + ,
                data.name,
                start_date+ ,
                end_date,
                data.amount,
            ] ).draw( false );
```

and to add css in datatable we can do like this :

```
var t = $(".docTable").DataTable({  
        'columnDefs': [
            {
                "targets": [0,1,3,4,6], // your case first column
                "className": "text-center",
            },
            {
                "targets": 2,
                "className": "text-left",
            },
            {
                "targets": 5,
                "className": "text-right",
            }
            ],
    });
```